# Graphing a point with a scale factor

Tags: javascript, graphics, canvas, 2d

I am centrally scaling a box on a graph with the following:

```
var x1 = (this.width - (this.image.width * this.scale)) / 2 + this.origin.x;
var y1 = (this.height - (this.image.height * this.scale)) / 2 + this.origin.y;
var x2 = (this.image.width * this.scale);
var y2 = (this.image.height * this.scale);
context.drawImage(this.image, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Now I need to be able to scale a single point on that graph. The point has an origin x / y, point x / y, and a scale factor (this.scale) at the current level. How can I translate this scale factor into a point on the box with the given scale?

Comment: Quite useful if you like matrix algebra like me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Scaling

Comment: @Blender: Any chance you can translate that into English for me? ;)

Comment: can you be a bit clearer with your question? I truthfully have no idea what you're asking. Maybe a picture could help?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is - a point has given coordinates `x,y` and you need to come up with the new x and y co-ordinates `a, b` so that its in the same place within the scaled box as it was in the whole graph.

The point is `x` units away horizontally from the origin, and you need it to be `x/scale` units from the new origin.

So, `a = x/scale + x1` ( because the new origin has coordinates `x1, y1` )

similarly, the point is `y` units vertically from the origin, and you need it to be `y/scale` units from the new origin.

and `b = y/scale + y1`

I think i may have misunderstood where the new origin is (the left corner of the box, but if I have then simply replace `x1` and `y1` with the coordinates of the new origin)